# Submit a certificate request file from a non domain computer. How to figure out policy server parameters

Tags: active-directory, security, windows-server-2012, certificate, ad-certificate-services

I'm trying to submit a certificate request. I'm trying to do it from command line so I can run it from code.

Previously I have done it by using the **Microsoft Active Directory Certificate Services** for the CA I'm using. Specifically **CA Web enrollment** where I copy and pastes the base 64 request in via the browser and then download the cert.

I'm trying to automate this using the [template below](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/098f858a-3e89-48d2-828e-274487033f6b/how-to-request-certificate-from-a-nondomain-computer?forum=winserversecurity). I have the server open (it's windows server 2012) and I can't figure out the correct paramters. I think the main thing I'm missing is the FQDN and Alias. How do I find this out?

```
certreq -submit 
-Username {domain}\{username} 
-p {password}
-PolicyServer "https://{FQDN CertificateEnrollmentPolicyWebService-Server/-Alias}/ADPolicyProvider_CEP_UsernamePassword/service.svc/CEP" 
-config "https://{FQDN CertificateEnrollentWebService-Server/-Alias}/{CAName}_CES_UsernamePassword/service.svc/CES" 
-attrib "CertificateTemplate:{TemplateName}" 
{Enter Path and Name of the Request-File}
{Choose Path and Filename for certificate}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are going to be the FQDNs of the web server(s) where you've installed the [Installing the Certificate Enrollment Policy Web Service](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd759214.aspx) and [Installing the Certificate Enrollment Web Service](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd759241.aspx) role features. Typically they'll be on the same server where you installed the CA.

Comment: @NathanCooper - It's likely the server running the CA. Try it and see.

Comment: I've checked IIS and there seems to be a certsrv and a certenroll. I've looked in both their folders and can't seem to find any cert enrolment policy files. I suspect I may have to stick to using the ui.